# How to validate filename length on file upload in Zend controller or form

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, long-filenames

I try to add a validator for the length of the filename which is uploaded from my Zend form.
I don't know whether I should add this validator in the **form itself** or to the `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` handling the upload. However, right now I'm trying the second thing - see code below. I want the controller to redirect with an error flag if the length of the filename to be uploaded exceeds 40 chars.
**`$upload` results in being valid even with a 41 chars long filename - why?**

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();

$upload->addValidators(
        array(
            array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(
                'min' => 0,
                'max' => 40))
        )
);

if (!$upload->isValid()) {
    $this->_redirect('/customer/uploadfile/groupid/'.$groupId.'/flag/XXX-TODO-Failure');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not validating anything with the code you have shown.

change the line as follows to reference the filename such as...

```
if(!$upload->isValid( $filenameToValidate ) {
```

... }

Also remember the filename is not a post but will be found in the $_FILES superglobal.

Comment: That did the trick! Maybe I was just too tired this day.

Just two additions:
1) In my code example, I didn't specify which StringLength validator attributes to set with '0' and '40', so the maximum string length was not even set correctly. I edited my example to set 'min' and 'max' explicitly.
2) I found out that I can get the filename of the upload with ZFs function $upload->getfilename('doc_path', false) instead of accessing $_FILES. I don't see which method would be recommended though.